# Javascript performance - Iterating over dom and adding listeners

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am currently working in a big web project where we have lots of dom elements which need a listener for click/change/... events. The first 500 lines of code of the main javascript file look like this.

```
$( ".bla" ).each(function(e) {
    $(this).on("click", function(){
        ... 
    });
});
```

So basically we add like 100 listeners and for each listener we have to iterate over the complete dom tree. I think this will take up considerable computation power. Is there something like a best practice solution to avoid this?

Comment: no need of `each` here. `$( ".bla" ).on("click", function(){` , is enough

Answer (score 0):

You can use event delegation:

```
$(document).on("click", ".bla", function(){
  // ...
});
```

Comment: It is called event delegation, not sure where you got live subscription.

Comment: Event delegation was handled by the `live` function until about 2011.

Comment: BUT that's  (event delegation) the correct way to handle it regarding performance, binding only one event listener

Comment: @A.Wolff, there is (or was) another [issue](//stackoverflow.com/q/34402369/4928642) about perfomance if using delegation.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you learned from the other answers that there was no need to use `each`.  However, there may not even be a need to select all elements with class `.bla` as in your example.

Rather, if a div, or some other element, contains all of the elements for which you are interested in handling a click event, you can put the event listener *on the container*, and then you determine which element got clicked by inspecting the `target` property of the event.  This works due to 'event propagation' -- if not handled directly handled on the element you clicked, the event will propagate up the DOM.

Simple example below with just two buttons.  This is straight Javascript which should easily enough be converted to JQuery -- hope it helps.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById('container').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
                alert('You clicked ' + event.target.innerHTML);
            });   
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <button id="fooButton" type="button">foo</button>
    <button id="barButton" type="button">bar</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```